# java error incompatible types when i compile

Tags: java, arrays, primes

here is my code and my problem is that i cant compile it ive included the error i get down below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class util3_2
{
        public static boolean IsPrime(int p)
        {
                for (int i = 2; i < p; i++)
                {
                        if (p % i == 0 && i != p)
                                return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
        public static int[] GetPrimes(int n)
        {
                List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                {
                        if(IsPrime(j))
                        {
                                arr.add(j);
                        }
                }
                return Arrays.asList(arr);
        }
}
```

here is my error

```
 error: incompatible types
                return Arrays.asList(arr);
                                    ^
  required: int[]
  found:    List<List<Integer>>
1 error
```

i have no idea what my error is.

Comment: You require an `int[]`, but you're providing a `List<List<Integer>>`. They're not the same thing.

Comment: change return value of your function to List<Integer> and return arr itself.

Answer (score -1):

You should return an array. Turn the list into an array by calling the toArray method on the list 'arr'.

Comment: You're never going to get an array of primitive `int` out of that list.